# Is a Lipschitz continuous gradient function is a Lipschitz function as well?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, optimization, continuity, uniform-continuity

Let $f(x)$ be a Lipschitz continuous gradient function, that is
$$
\|f'(x)-f'(y)\| \leq \alpha \|x-y\|
$$
where $\|\cdot\| $ is Euclidean norm and $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n$.
Can we prove that the function is a Lipschitz function, that is
$$
|f(x)-f(y)| \leq L \|x-y\|
$$
If so, is there any relationship between $\alpha$ and $L$?

Comment: Did you try to see what happens when $n=1$?

Comment: Try with $f(x) = x^2$. $f'$ is globally Lipschitz, $f$ is not.